# How to select a class and manipulate it

Tags: jquery

I want to select a class that satisfies the condition with a value of `"1t"` and replace it with an `"ok"`, but I can't do it.

```js
$(".flip-container").each(function() {
  var t = $(this).find(".front").text();
  if (t == '1t') {
    $('.front').text('Ok');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
  <div>
      <div>
          <div class="back">back</div>
          <a><div class="front">1t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">2t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">3t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">4t</div></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wz7xpfj/1/

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `$(this).find(".front").text()` is finding all the `.front` elements, so the returned value from `text()` is `1t2t3t4t`.

To do what you require you could target the `.front` elements using the `:contains()` selector to find only those which have the `1t` text within them:

```js
$('.front:contains("1t")').text('Ok');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="back">back</div>
      <a><div class="front">1t</div></a>
      <a><div class="front">2t</div></a>
      <a><div class="front">3t</div></a>
      <a><div class="front">4t</div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flip-container">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="back">back</div>
      <a><div class="front">1t</div></a>
      <a><div class="front">2t</div></a>
      <a><div class="front">3t</div></a>
      <a><div class="front">4t</div></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

here change

```js
$(".flip-container .front").each(function() {
  var t = $(this).text();
  if (t == '1t') {
    $(this).text('Ok');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
  <div>
      <div>
          <div class="back">back</div>
          <a><div class="front">1t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">2t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">3t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">4t</div></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the selector [`".front:contains(text)"`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Your code is then:

```js
$(".flip-container").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".front:contains(1t)").text("Ok")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip-container">
  <div>
      <div>
          <div class="back">back</div>
          <a><div class="front">1t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">2t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">3t</div></a>
          <a><div class="front">4t</div></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're using `:contains()`, you don't need the `each()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That depends on the context. I could of course use the selector `$(".flip-container .front:contains(t1)")`. But I don't know what the OP wants. I assume that this is a minimal example from some bigger code. Plus that the OP is not that used to writing javascript. Therefore I changed as less code as possible to show exactly where the point is to make it work. I see no point in restructuring the whole code or making it more complicated than necessary.